Verify $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to -1} \frac{x+1}{x^2-1}=-\frac{1}{2}$
The problem:
Verify $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to -1} \frac{x+1}{x^2-1}=-\frac{1}{2}$.
What I have tried:
$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to -1} \frac{x+1}{x^2-1}=-\frac{1}{2} \iff \lim_{x\to -1} \frac{x+1}{(x+1)(x-1)}=-\frac{1}{2} \iff \lim_{x\to -1} \frac{1}{(x-1)}=-\frac{1}{2}$
We want to find $\delta \gt 0$ so that if $0 \lt \vert x-(-1) \vert \lt \delta \iff 0 \lt \vert x+1 \vert \lt \delta$, then
$\vert f(x) - (-\frac{1}{2}) \vert \lt \epsilon \iff \vert f(x) +\frac{1}{2} \vert \lt \epsilon$.
$\vert f(x) +\frac{1}{2} \vert \lt \epsilon \iff -\epsilon \lt f(x)+\frac{1}{2} \lt \epsilon \Rightarrow -\epsilon \lt \frac{1}{x-1}+\frac{1}{2} \lt \epsilon \iff -\epsilon - \frac{1}{2}\lt \frac{1}{x-1} \lt \epsilon -\frac{1}{2}$
And this is where I get stuck.
My question:
How do I get $x$ to be alone?

Do you need an $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proof?  Or can you use basic continuity results about limits?

This is a practice problem I am not being graded solving and the chapter is about $\epsilon- \delta$ proof so I'd prefer being able to solve it using just that.

If $-\frac 12 -\epsilon < \frac 1{x-1} <- \frac 12 + \epsilon < 0$ then what is the boundary for $x$.  Use that to find $\delta$.

I am still very confused. Is my next step to write $\vert \frac{1}{x-1} \vert \lt -\frac{1}{2}+ \epsilon$?

Or should my next step perhaps be $\frac{1}{-\frac{1}{2}- \epsilon} \lt x-1 \lt \frac{1}{-\frac{1}{2}+ \epsilon}$?

Continuing the way of the comment above gives me $\delta=-\frac{1}{1+2 \epsilon}$. Is this right?

Roll up your sleeves and do algebra on fractions.  Figure you how to write $\frac 1{-\frac 12-\epsilon} < x-1 < \frac 1{-\frac 12+\epsilon}\implies 1+\frac 1{-\frac 12-\epsilon}< x <1+\frac 1{-\frac 12+\epsilon}$ as $-1 -\delta < x < -1 + \delta$.  This involves figuring out $1 +\frac 1{-\frac 12-\epsilon} = -1 + ???$

Flip them
$-\frac 12 -\epsilon < \frac 1{x-1} < -\frac 12 + \epsilon$.  We can assume $\epsilon < \frac 12$ and these are all negative so
$-\frac 12 -\epsilon < \frac 1{x-1} < -\frac 12 + \epsilon < 0$
$0< \frac 12 -\epsilon < \frac 1{1-x} < \frac 12 + \epsilon$
$\frac 1{\frac 12 - \epsilon} > 1-x > \frac 1{\frac 12 + \epsilon} > 0$
$-\frac 1{\frac 12 + \epsilon} < x-1< -\frac 1{\frac 12 - \epsilon} < 0$
$1-\frac 1{\frac 12 +\epsilon} < x < 1 -\frac 1{\frac 12 -\epsilon}$.
Okay.... Let's try to simplify those terms
$\frac 1{\frac 12 \pm \epsilon}=\frac 2{1\pm 2\epsilon}=\frac {2\pm 4\epsilon\mp 4\epsilon}{1\pm 2\epsilon}=2 \mp \frac {4\epsilon}{1\pm 2\epsilon}$ so we have:
$-1-\frac {4\epsilon}{1+2\epsilon}< x <-1+\frac {4\epsilon}{1-2\epsilon}$
So if we have assume 1) $\epsilon < \frac 12$ and 2) $\delta \le \min(\frac {4\epsilon}{1+2\epsilon},\frac {4\epsilon}{1-2\epsilon})=\frac {4\epsilon}{1+2\epsilon}$ we will be good.
[If $\epsilon\ge \frac 12$ we just take $\delta = \frac {4\frac 12}{1+2\frac 12}=1$.  If $|x+1|<1$ then $-2 < x < 0$ and $-3 < x-1 < -1$ and $-1 < \frac 1{x-1}=\frac {x+1}{x^2-1} < -\frac 13$ and $-\frac 12 < \frac {x+1}{x^2-1}+\frac 12 < -\frac 16 < 0$ so $|\frac{x+1}{x^2-1}-(-\frac 12)|<\frac 12 \le \epsilon$]
[And if $\epsilon < \frac 12$ and $\delta = \frac {4\epsilon}{1+2\epsilon}<1$ then $|x-(-1)| < \delta$ would mean $-1-\delta  < x < -1 + \delta$ so $-2-\delta < x-1 < -2+\delta$ so $-2-\frac {4\epsilon}{1-2\epsilon}<-2-\frac {4\epsilon}{1+2\epsilon} < x-1<-2+\frac {4\epsilon}{1+2\epsilon}$ and $-\frac 12 -\epsilon =-\frac 1{2+\frac{4\epsilon}{1-2\epsilon}} < \frac 1{x-1}<-\frac 1{2-\frac {4\epsilon}{1+2\epsilon}}=-\frac 12 +\epsilon$ and so $|\frac 1{x-1} + \frac 12| < \epsilon$ and so $|\frac{x+1}{x^2-1} -(-\frac 12)| < \epsilon$]

Small error, $\frac{x+1}{x^2-1}=\frac1{x-1} \neq \frac1{x+1}$.

Yeah... I realized that.

I am definitely overstepping boundaries here, but do you have discord where we could possibly video and/or voice chat and you could explain some of the intermediate steps? I am still not understanding.

I don't see how we will be able to do chat.  Can you point out which intermediary steps have issues.

This is one of the steps I am having issues with: $\frac 1{\frac 12 \pm \epsilon}=\frac 2{1\pm 2\epsilon}=\frac {2\pm 4\epsilon\mp 4\epsilon}{1\pm 2\epsilon}=2 \mp \frac {4\epsilon}{1\pm 2\epsilon}$. What in the world is being done here?

It's just arithmetic. $\frac 1{\frac 12 + e}=\frac {1\times 2}{(\frac 12 + e)\times 2}=\frac 2{1+2e}=\frac {2 + 0}{1+2e}=\frac{2+4e - 4e}{1+2e}=\frac {(2+4e)-4e}{1+2e}=\frac {2+4e}{1+2e}+\frac{-4e}{1+2e}= 2 -\frac {4e}{1+2e}$.

Find $\delta$ such that:
$|x+1| < \delta \implies |\frac {1}{x-1} + \frac 12| < \epsilon\\  
|\frac {2 + (x-1)}{2(x-1)}|\\
|\frac {x+1}{2(x-1)}|\\
|\frac {x+1}{2(x-1)}| < \left |\frac {\delta}{2(x-1)}\right|$
We need to find a way to bound $\left|\frac {1}{x-1}\right|$
When $\delta < 1, x< 0$ and $\left|\frac {1}{x-1}\right| < 1$
Let $\delta = \min (1, 2\epsilon)$
$|x+1| < \delta \implies |\frac {x+1}{2(x-1)}| < \epsilon$
